# Cannot create second cascading FK relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Memberships](
    [MembershipId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsUserAdmin] [bit] NOT NULL
 )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gifts](
    [GiftId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MembershipId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimedByMembershipId] [int] NULL
 )
```

A membership can have many gifts associated with it.  When a membership is deleted, I need to do two things:

1. Delete any gifts associated with that `MembershipId`.
2. For any records with `ClaimedByMembershipId` equal to the `MembershipId` of the Membership being deleted, set `ClaimedByMembershipId` to `NULL`.

I'm attempting to implement this cascading through Management Studio's UI.  I can accomplish #1 by the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gifts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Gifts_Memberships] 
FOREIGN KEY([MembershipId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Memberships] ([MembershipId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

For #2, I'm unable to save the table after creating the key which I believe would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gifts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Gifts_Memberships1] 
FOREIGN KEY([ClaimedByMembershipId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Memberships] ([MembershipId])
ON NULL CASCADE
GO
```

I get the following error:

```
'Memberships' table saved successfully
'Gifts' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Gifts_Memberships1'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Gifts_Memberships1' on table 'Gifts' may cause cycles 
or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify 
other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's exactly like the error says.   You can't create cyclical cascade paths.   If TableA can cause a cascading delete on TableB, then TableB cannot cause cascading deletes on TableA.   Period.   Even if in your specific case it logically seems like it should be ok, SQL Server won't allow it.  No option to override.

Best you can do is handle your #2 requirement with a trigger.